# Fonts look strange after migrating from flex 4.1 to 4.6

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, fonts, flex4.6

I'm migrating from sdk 4.1 to 4.6. And now fonts look weird.

**4.1**

[image: 4.1]

**4.6**

[image: 4.6]

You can notice, that in 4.6 fonts look more smooth. Font declaration:

```
@font-face {
    src: url("/assets/UNVR57X.TTF");
    fontFamily: myCFFFont;
    embedAsCFF: true;
    renderingMode: normal;
}
```

I use `s:Label` component.

I tried `renderingMode` both `true` and `false`. How can I make it look as it looks in 4.1? Thanks

Comment: I believe you should set `embedAsCFF` to `true` for Spark components.

Comment: @RIAstar Sorry, I've given wrong css. Now edited. Any ideas?.. Thanks

Comment: Hmmm how odd, as a suggestion, you can change the font managers that are used to embed the font, its worth a shot! http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=fonts_06.html, also have you traced out the list of embedded fonts, to be sure its definitely embedded?

Comment: Try setting advancedAntiAliasing to true. If that doesn't help, check out the subsection "Using embedded fonts > Using advanced anti-aliasing" in the previous link to tweak sharpness and thickness.

Answer (score 0):

Are you publishing to Flash Player or AIR?

If to AIR, [here's one bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242622/device-font-looks-different-in-flash-player-air) with displaying fonts in AIR, maybe it's your case.

(Also, setting cacheAsBitmap=true causes similar effect as yours).